# Effects on imges behaving differently

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created image effect gallery in jsfiddle

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/4qkk1Lpn/)
I tried to implement in on my website , but the effect and result is different than in the jsfiddle.

My html structure looks like this

```
<body id="body">
<div class="main">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li data-href="ponuka">Ponuka</li>
            <li data-href="montaz" data-script="lightbox">montáž pohonov KEY</li>
            <li data-href="vyrobky" data-script="slide">výrobký</li>
            <li data-href="partneri">partneri</li>
            <li data-href="kontakt">kontakt</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="info">

    <div class="vyrobky">
<div class="vyrobky_holder">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
      <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
       <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
       <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
       <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
       <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
</div></div>



</div><script class="delete_script" src="slide.js"></script></body>
```

css looks like this

```
.vyrobky{
    width:1250px;
    height: 600px;
    //overflow-y:hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -100px;

}
.vyrobky_holder{
        width:1250px;
        height: 410px;
     -webkit-transition:1.5s ease all;
     -webkit-animation: mymove .5s ;
     margin-top: 0px;
     position: relative;
}
.vyrobky_holder ul{
     position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.vyrobky_holder ul li{
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid black;
    list-style-type:none
}
.vyrobky_holder ul li img{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.vyrobky .vyrobky_image{

    width:150px;
    height:150px;
     -webkit-transition:.5s ease all;
     -webkit-animation: mymove .5s ;

}
```

and of course i adjusted js , on website it looks like this

```
var one = document.querySelectorAll(".vyrobky_image img");
var nav = document.getElementsByClassName("vyrobky_holder")[0];
var tmp_left=document.getElementsByClassName("vyrobky")[0];
nav.onmousemove=trick;
 var el = document.querySelector('.info');
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);

      var left = style['margin-left'];
        var top=el.offsetTop;
  /*alert(
      "Top:" + top + '\n' +
      "Left:" + left
  );*/
 function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
    return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offsetLeft +parseInt(left) + (elem.offsetWidth / 2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offsetTop + 189+(elem.offsetHeight / 2)), 2)));
}
function trick(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;



    for (var i = 0; i < one.length; i++) {
        if (one[i] == e.currentTarget) continue;
        var vektor = calculateDistance(one[i], x, y);

        if (vektor <= 150) {
            var cislo=1.5+((100-vektor)*0.01); //scale
            var cislo_2=0.5+((100-vektor)*0.01); //opacity
            if(cislo>1.5)cislo=1.5;
            one[i].style.transform="scale("+cislo+")";
            //one[i].style.opacity=cislo_2;

        }
        else{
        one[i].style.transform="scale(1)";
            //one[i].style.opacity=0.5;
        }
    }
}
```

The problems are following : z-index on hovered element does not have an effect, and the scaling image based on distance from mouse does not work as it should , it works for elements that are on the left side of mouse , but not on those that are on the right side of the mouse or above / under image. How can i fix this unwanted behavior?
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/rsk8k550/) is how the images effect behaves on my site , as you can see coming closer with mouse to the images on right(if mouse is on any image) doesnt effect those images on right

Comment: putting it on a fiddle or snippet would be nice for these questions..

Comment: @ewrwr a fiddle is linked in the question. The code works there.

Comment: sorry didnt see that @Pointy

Comment: The jsfiddle site by default wraps the code in the JavaScript cell inside a "load" event handler. Did you do that in your real site?

Comment: no, i am changing content of site with ajax and creating new script with code that i posted , so onload would do nothing i tried it

Comment: i updated question , i linked jsfiddle where images behaves exactly like on my site.